# jquery - Remove class from parent in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a Javascript `IF` statement that detects if:

```
$('.ms-quickLaunch .menu ul.static li a .menu-item-text') == "Manage"
```

And if it does equal "Manage" then set the list to `.show().`

```
<ul class="root static">
    <li class="static linksBelow">
        <a href="#" class="static menu-item">
            <span class="additional-background">
                <span class="menu-item-text">Manage</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="static" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:open();" class="static menu-item">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                        <span class="menu-item-text">Manage List</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="static menu-item">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                        <span class="menu-item-text">Manage Documents</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('.ms-quickLaunch .menu ul.static .menu-item-text').html() == "Manage") {
    $('.ms-quickLaunch .menu ul.static').show();
}
```

(I have removed a couple of unnecessary elements from your selector to make it more efficient)

Answer (score 0):

ok maybe you can [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/unTWR/).
but if it's possible, it's better to add id to all those lines to avoid possible clash.

```
<ul class="root static">
    <li class="static linksBelow">
        <a href="#" class="static menu-item">
            <span class="additional-background">
                <span class="menu-item-text">Manage</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="static" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:open();" class="static menu-item">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                        <span class="menu-item-text">Manage List</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="static menu-item">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                        <span class="menu-item-text">Manage Documents</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

if($("li.linksBelow span.menu-item-text").html().toLowerCase()=="manage"){
    $("ul.static ul.static").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchor = $('.ms-quickLaunch .menu ul.static li a');
if ($('.menu-item-text', anchor).html() === "Manage")
{
    anchor.next("ul").show();
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/zX4tZ/)**